# Configuring cloud Firestore beta with cloud Firebase function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am going to use cloud Firestore for NoSQL database. Please let me know the steps to configure with cloud Firebase functions.

1. What dependencies, I have to include in `package.json`?
2. how to configure in firebase cloud functions?
3. how to check firebase functions connection with cloud firestore?
4. In the database of firebase console, I can see add collections, If I click on that, it is opening one pop-up "Add data", what i have to do with that?.
5. what is purpose of storage?
6. what is document?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Questions that feature lists of sub-questions do not work very well on Stack Overflow, and are generally considered 'too broad'. This is because it encourages questions of the 'how do I start' form, and the correct answer is to read the introductory docs. I understand the value of hand-holding when starting a new technology - it's like having a learning buddy - but that's not really what Stack Overflow is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some short answers:

**[1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)** This depends on from where you wan't to interact with firestore. Is
it from an Angular app (angularfire2), React (reactfire), Vanilla js
(firebase-js-sdk), Node.js serverside (firebase-admin) etc.

**[2 & 3]** Firebase cloud functions take some time to configure, but there is great documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). It is relatively easy to get started, and the connection to firestore is managed by the `firebase-functions` sdk.

**[4]** You can simply use that functionality to add data directly from the console, maybe to create some mock data.

**[5]** Storage is for saving photos, videos, large documents, text files etc.

**[6]** In the firebase/firestore universe, a document (together with collections) is a key concept of firestore. To get a very good introduction to firestore, I can highly recommend this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ).

Welcome to the firebase eco system. It's a great platform with many features, and sometimes it can be difficult to understand the purpose of everything. But a good advice from me would be to try to only ask very specific programming questions. For example: "I am using this firebase SDK, and trying to update a document like this and expect to see X as the result but I get an error. Why is that?"